C# Math.Round() result is unpredictable
I have encountered this issue in my .NET Framework 4.8 project, but it also can be reproduced in .NET 8 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-8.0#code-try-2).
// incorrect rounding (double)
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(71.335, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 71.33 (must to be 71.34)
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(72.335, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 72.33 (must to be 72.34)
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(73.335, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 73.33 (must to be 73.34)

// correct rounding (double)
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(60.335, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 60.34
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(83.335, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 83.34

// correct rounding (decimal) which was incorrect for double
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(71.335M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 71.34
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(72.335M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 72.34
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(73.335M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 73.34

I don't understand what is the difference between 71.335, 72.335, etc.  and 60.335, 83.335, etc. which makes Math.Round() behave differently.

This is another instance of Is floating-point math broken? double cannot represent values such as 71.335 precisely. The actual value is a little less than 71.335.

71.335 (double) is actually more like 71.3349999999999937472239253111183643341064453125, 72.335 (double) like 72.3349999999999937472239253111183643341064453125, 60.335 (double) like 60.33500000000000085265128291212022304534912109375 etc

This behavior is the same in all CPUs and programming languages languages. The exact behavior specified in the IEEE 754 standard. The inherent lack of precision in floating point numbers also means that any arithmetic operations, even addition, introduce errors. It also means you can't just compare two floats for equality, you can only check if their difference is less than a specific limit.
